# scoping for "variable:" query in get-item of powershell

Tags: powershell

get-item in powershell, when used to get a global variable, does not seem to work.  Certainly it is not consistent with the behaviour of set-item, remove-item or test-path.  In particular, can someone explain the output from this script?

```
#
#Script to execute
#
$Global:g_test="Hello World"
test-path "variable:\Global:g_test"
$Global:g_test
set-item -path "variable:\Global:g_test" -value "Goodbye Cruel World"
$Global:g_test
$Global:g_test.getType()
write-host '$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:\Global:g_test).value'
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:\Global:g_test).value
$l_tmp
$l_tmp.gettype()
write-host '$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:\Global:g_test").value'
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:\Global:g_test").value
$l_tmp
$l_tmp.gettype()
write-host '$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:Global:g_test).value'
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:Global:g_test).value
$l_tmp
$l_tmp.gettype()
write-host '$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:Global:g_test").value'
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:Global:g_test").value
$l_tmp
$l_tmp.gettype()
remove-item "variable:\Global:g_test"
test-path "variable:\Global:g_test"
```

Expected output:

```
True
Hello World
Goodbye Cruel World

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                    
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:\Global:g_test).value
Goodbye Cruel World

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                    
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:\Global:g_test").value
Goodbye Cruel World

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                    
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:Global:g_test).value
Goodbye Cruel World

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                    
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:Global:g_test").value
Goodbye Cruel World

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                    

False
```

Actual output:

```
True
Hello World
Goodbye Cruel World

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                    
$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:\Global:g_test).value
Property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:11 char:11
+     $l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:\Global:g_test).value
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:13 char:2
+     $l_tmp.gettype()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:\Global:g_test").value
Property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:15 char:11
+     $l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:\Global:g_test").value
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:17 char:2
+     $l_tmp.gettype()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:Global:g_test).value
Property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:19 char:11
+     $l_tmp=$(get-item -path  variable:Global:g_test).value
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:21 char:2
+     $l_tmp.gettype()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

$l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:Global:g_test").value
Property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:23 char:11
+     $l_tmp=$(get-item -path  "variable:Global:g_test").value
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\redacted\testing.ps1:25 char:2
+     $l_tmp.gettype()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

False

#>
```

The point is, `get-item -path  variable:\Global:g_test` doesn't fail, but instead just returns $null, rather than the variable requested.  Yes, I am aware I can use "$(get-variable g_test -scope Global).value", but there are other reasons why I am am trying to use get-item rather than get-variable.  Thanks.

Comment: Global variables are always reachable without `global:` unless you have an intermediate scoped variable with the same name that hides the global. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am writing some utility functions for a small library.  The library is to be used by other developers.  As such, I cannot predict what other variables there may be in intermediate scopes.  While I can (and have) written working code using "get-variable" instead of "get-item", the code needs also to access env: variables.  If I could have used the "variable:global:g_xxx" construct, the code would have been more elegant and uniform.  I just cannot fathom why it should work for set-item, remove-item and test-path, yet _silently_ fail for get-item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with get-item or perhaps a bug that the other commands do allow "global:" in the path.

Comment: Well, why does that not also apply to set-item, remove-item and test-path?  I.e. why is the behaviour of get-item inconsistent with the other three (all of whose behaviour is consistent)?

Comment: "That" is the question that's been posed on the PowerShell MVP mail list. It does seem inconsistent. If I learn anything, I'll report back.

Comment: Thanks. Do mailings on the PowerShell MVP mail list appear anywhere on line that I can monitor or look?  thanks.

Comment: No, the mail list is private and is intended for communication between MVPs and the PowerShell product team. It frequently includes topics that are under NDA.

Comment: Heard back that this is a bug but since there is an easy workaround (use Get-Variable) the odds of it getting fixed are low. Unless a lot of folks vote to get it fixed.  I submitted the bug.  You can vote on it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/807910/variable-drive-paths-with-global-prefix-in-the-path-do-not-work-with-get-item

Comment: Thanks very much.  Really appreciate the effort.